# Why use OneToOne or ManyToOne relationships with JPA. What are the advantages?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-one

I'm trying to understand why should I use OneToOne and ManyToOne relationships with JPA. A google search offered no insight into this, I could only find "when" to use them.

I understand "when" I should use them, but not the "why".
What are the advantages? What would happen if I didn't annotate a field with one of these relationships?

Comment: Using these annotations saves you from writing native SQL to obtain related entities from the database but rather encapsulates the logic behind the appropriate Java concept. Also, if you're not having an actual coding problem SO might not be the best place for asking this question.